# Unable to Open Cash Sale Form in customization Editor in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am Unable to Open Cash Sale Screen in Customization Editor of Acumatica, after I have added a new tab control with a Grid inside. I have assigned a custom DataView in the data member property of the Grid Control.

It Gives up the following error "The Customization Project Must Be Published before the screen can be edited. Error : The View CommissionCalcView does not exist".

Here "CommissionCalcView" is the name of my custom view, and it is Present in ARCashSaleEntry Extension of my project.

My Code Goes here....

```
using COMMISSIONMAPPING;
using PX.Objects.AR.Standalone;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
  public class ARCashSaleEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARCashSaleEntry>
  {
    public PXSelect<CommissionCalculation, 
        Where<CommissionCalculation.cashSaleDocType,
            Equal<ARCashSale.docType>,
        And<CommissionCalculation.cashSaleRefNbr, 
            Equal<ARCashSale.refNbr>>>> CommissionCalcView;
    #region Event Handlers

    #endregion
  }
}
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvjRi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the development process and missing dlls, i removed the dll from the bin folder of my website and removed any key fields from my DAC, and rebuilt the project,
The problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this many times as well.  The problem for me tends to be an error in how I define fields in a DAC extension or in improperly defining the view in the form.

In this case, you have BQL that is trying to compare CommissionCalculation (table selected in the BQL) to ARCashSale (table not selected in the BQL).  Try adding Current<> on the ARCashSale references in the view so that it pulls the current value from the cache for ARCashSale in the base graph.

```
using COMMISSIONMAPPING;
using PX.Objects.AR.Standalone;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
  public class ARCashSaleEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARCashSaleEntry>
  {
    public PXSelect<CommissionCalculation, 
        Where<CommissionCalculation.cashSaleDocType,
            Equal<Current<ARCashSale.docType>>,
        And<CommissionCalculation.cashSaleRefNbr, 
            Equal<Current<ARCashSale.refNbr>>>>> CommissionCalcView;
    #region Event Handlers

    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: This generally happens because of few key fields in the DAC we are using. We need to design or DAC or DAC extension very cautiously.